# Inserting Bulk data taking lot of time Sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am trying to insert 1120 records (records=questions since it is trivia game) in my database but it is taking around 20secs i can't even work with insertHelper because it has been deprecated in android.
i searched a lot and used **beginTransaction()**,**setTransactionSuccessful()** & **db.endTransaction();** but nothing helped. maybe i haven't used them correct so please correct me if it's wrong

HelperClass

```
private void addingeachquestions(Questions question) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(QUESTION, question.getQUESTION());
        values.put(OPTION1, question.getOPT1());
        values.put(ANSWER, question.getANSWER());
        values.put(ANSWER2, question.getANSWER2());
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
}

public void addquestions() {
    //famous people
    Questions q1 = new Questions("Who was the first African American to have served as president of United States of America ?", "BAROBAACKMAQCAEMBD", "BARACK", "OBAMA");
    this.addingeachquestions(q1);
    Questions q2 = new Questions("Who co-founded Apple company with Steve Wozniak, Ronald Wayne ?", "TSOVWIBYUBZRGOEJSE", "STEVE", "JOBS");
    this.addingeachquestions(q2);
```

MainActivityClass

```
demoHelperClass = new DemoHelperClass(this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = demoHelperClass.getWritableDatabase();
    demoHelperClass.addquestions();
```

Comment: `addquestions()` or `addingeachquestions(Questions question)` ?

Comment: Put all your inserts inside one transaction. See the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088056/how-to-bulk-insert-in-sqlite-in-android

Comment: Is this something you absolutely have to do in the app? Can't you just package the pre-populated database with your app?

Comment: @John Joe i have updated the question please check !!!

Comment: @aljo i have previous gone throw that but i didn't understand how they have used loop after content values. can u please tell in my case how it will work

Comment: @Mike M i didn't got you can you please elaborate !!!

Comment: I mean, make the database yourself, and package _that_ in your app, instead of the text file - or whatever - you're using to create the database after installation. Follow me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can collect your data, put it in a list, then iterate through the list inside a transaction like so:

```
private void addAllQuestions(Arraylist<Questions> allQuestions) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        for (Questions question: allQuestions) {
            values.put(QUESTION, question.getQUESTION());
            values.put(OPTION1, question.getOPT1());
            values.put(ANSWER, question.getANSWER());
            values.put(ANSWER2, question.getANSWER2());
            db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);        
        }

        db.setTransactionSuccessful();

    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
}

public void addquestions() {
    //famous people
    ArrayList<Questions> allQuestions = new ArrayList<Questions>();

    allQuestions.append(new Questions("Who was the first African American to have served as president of United States of America ?", "BAROBAACKMAQCAEMBD", "BARACK", "OBAMA"));

    allQuestions.append(new Questions("Who co-founded Apple company with Steve Wozniak, Ronald Wayne ?", "TSOVWIBYUBZRGOEJSE", "STEVE", "JOBS"));

    this.addAllQuestions(allQuestions);
}
```

Based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32088155/4268599

Answer (score 1):

I **have used** below method for around **1,00,000 rows insert** and definitely faster than other. You can try it.

Instead of one bye one data insert, directly `beginTransaction` and insert all data and complete transaction.

Add below code(function) in `DatabaseHelper`(/DbHelper) class and call that function with arraylist of custom class(DataModel class).

Make some adding/changes as per your requirement:-

```
public void insertBigDataQuickly(ArrayList<DataModel> arrayList) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();   //db is instance of DatabaseHelper(/DBHelper) class
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        String sql = "Insert or Replace into table_name (column1, column2, column3) values(?,?,?)";
        SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement(sql);
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {  //Loop to insert all data one-by-one with Arraylist data
            DataModel singleData = arrayList.get(i);
            statement.bindString(1, singleData.getValue1());    //1 - Index value of column
            statement.bindLong(2, singleData.getValue2());      //2 - Index value of column
            statement.bindDouble(3, singleData.getValue3());    //3 - Index value of column
            statement.executeInsert();
        }

        db.setTransactionSuccessful(); // This commits the transaction
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Database error: ",e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
    db.close();
}
```