# insert 5000 records in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, gson

which is the best way to insert 5000 products(name and price) in sqlite?
I try not to use 5000 inserts one below the other like that:

```
 db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +tableprod+" (id_prod, name) VALUES (7791234567898, 'chocolate')");
```

Should I use json and gson and don't use sqlite?Thanks.

Comment: Where does the data come from? Do you already know it?

Comment: The data is supposed to be in the database or somewhere where the user can retrieve through the Id

Comment: You did not answer my question. Where do these values (`7791234567898`, `chocolate`) come from?

Answer (score 1):

Adding one by one would be slow. You can use `Batch` insert, using which you can insert all the 5000 records in just one transaction. Something like:

```
// Init SQLiteDatabase
database.beginTransaction();
// do ALL your inserts here
db.setTransactionSuccessful()
db.endTransaction();
```

For more details see [how to bulk insert in sqlite in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088056/how-to-bulk-insert-in-sqlite-in-android) and [Squeezing Performance from SQLite: Insertions](https://medium.com/@JasonWyatt/squeezing-performance-from-sqlite-insertions-971aff98eef2).

Hope this helps.