# how to store the huge API response (JSON) in sqlLite using chunks

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin

I want to store the API response in sqlLite. API reponse is in JSON Format and contain huge data. Due to this application stop working. How can i solve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Define 'huge'. If you deserialize JSON in memory, then the issue happens long before you hit sqlite...

Comment: Its more than 13 MB data

Comment: That's tiny. Please include some code then.

Comment: I am doing like this...
foreach (var Item in jArr)
{   tbl.Name = Item["Name"].ToString() ;
    database.Insert(tbl);}

Comment: `application stop working` how exactly? Does it throw exceptions? Which exactly?

Comment: I think you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088056/how-to-bulk-insert-in-sqlite-in-android

Comment: when json is inseting into sqllite then a pop up message came with close app and wait

Comment: @DheerajSharma Do it on a background thread so you do not block the main/UI thread and cause an ANR.

Comment: 13MB data is highly not reccomended. you must have to refine your service.

Comment: `pop up message came with close app and wait` that is probably because you are working with the DB on the UI thread.

Comment: store it in a file and get read that file when you need the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time it is bad practice to have all JSON  in the local store in mobile it makes your API call heavy and mobile speed and performance slow it also affects your third party libraries as well so solution is to make two individual DB SQLite and in which mapped on transitional data in one DB and rest in other so every time you will get live and fast data via transitional table or SQLitestore.